# How to fix "curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer" error when doing a port mapping from docker container to host machine?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers, port

I have a Angular Project running in a docker container at port 4200. I have done a port mapping from docker container's 4200 port to my localhost 4200.

I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04. When doing `netstat -nltp`, I get output

`tcp6       0      0 :::4200                 :::*                    LISTEN`

My Dockerfile looks like :

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I expected when running curl :::4200, to show me the webpage sourcecode instead of the error,
`curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: How do you run the container?Launching your app from browser works?

Comment: And does the Node process actually listen on port 4200?  (Express's default is often 3000; the EXPOSE directive and the right-hand side of `docker run -p` need to match the internal port number.)

Comment: @leopal Yes, the app works just fine!

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, the node process is listening to port 400. I have a Dockerfile defined which port maps it from 4200:42000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the following in `package.json` for my angular project did the trick.

**BEFORE**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

**AFTER**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Follow [this](http://imaginativethinking.ca/heck-get-connection-reset-peer-containerizing-angular-4-application/) link for further details

Answer (score 0):

Perform a port mapping when running the container for the first time as

```
docker run -ti --name angular angular_image:latest -p 4200:4200
```

This will override the EXPOSE command in the dockerfile. In real docker would have allocated a random port mapping from the container  to the host machine. So, it is necessary to have a port mapping the docker cli.

Comment: I have a docker-compose file which does the same.
`    services:
     angular: 
      build: Client 
      ports:
      - "4200:4200"`